# Setting User Agent for HtmlUnitDriver Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I set the user agent property for HtmlUnitDriver in Selenium Java ?
I can set it for the firefox driver with

```
FirefoxProfile ffp = new FirefoxProfile();
ffp.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8; Zune 4.7");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffp);
```

Is there a way to do this for HtmlUnitDriver ?
I've tried to use the setCapability("UserAgentName", "some UA settings"); but this does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try using DesiredCapabilities?

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capabilities.setBrowserName(<browser_name>);
capabilities.setPlatform(<platform>);
capabilities.setVersion(<version>);
driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I have a text file with the user agent settings in each line.
In your above code, do I have to parse the line and find out the browser name, platform and version ?
Eg of a line will be 

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; GTB7.3; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; ShopperReports 3.0.497.0; SRS_IT_E8790571BC76585634A191)

Comment: I think parsing the string would be necessary. You can either set the capabilities as mentioned in the answer or you can use `DesiredCapabilities(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> rawMap)` to put the values into a Map and assign it to the object.

Answer (score 4):

Setting custom User Agent string for **HtmlUnitDriver**:

```
final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20160101 Firefox/66.0";

WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(new BrowserVersion(
                "Firefox", "5.0 (Windows)", USER_AGENT, 66 //important is 3rd argument
));
```

It works. I tested it on http://myhttp.info for getting user agent from remote server

*(OS: W7, Selenium version: 2.37.1, Java 7u45 x64)*

```
@Test
public void testUserAgent() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://myhttp.info");
    MyHttpInfoPage myHttpInfoPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, MyHttpInfoPage.class);
    String userAgent = myHttpInfoPage.getUserAgent(); // @FindBy(xpath = "//td[text()='User agent']/following-sibling::td")
    Assert.assertEquals(userAgent, USER_AGENT);
}
```

---

(see also [BrowserVersion](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html) JavaDoc)

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit has [recently updated their internals](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/commit/431e20edc22f0ed9da45f2acdc975183be55f8e0) regarding browser versions. Now to change the emulated browser version, which sets the user-agent string, you have to specify the browser `version` capability, such as:

#### Chrome (default)

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capabilities.setVersion(org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType.CHROME);
WebDriver myDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

#### Internet Explorer

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capabilities.setVersion(org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType.IE);
WebDriver myDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

#### Firefox (no firefox version specified, defaults to 52)

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
capabilities.setVersion(org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType.FIREFOX);
WebDriver myDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

#### Firefox (specifying one of the two available versions: 45 or 52)

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.htmlUnit();
// specify ff version 45
capabilities.setVersion(org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType.FIREFOX + "-45");
// ...or specify ff version 52
capabilities.setVersion(org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType.FIREFOX + "-52");
WebDriver myDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(capabilities);
```

The above are all of the available versions [as of today](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/blob/2.27/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.java#L320).

To verify if they changed, check [their master branch](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/blob/master/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.java#L322).